# Facebook Jquery SDK FB.init() not initializing

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am a beginner when it comes to back-end programming and API access.
I have a simple ajax request to the JQuery SDK that I copied from Facebook's documentation page but it seems not to be working.

My code is the following:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
$.getScript('http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js', function(){
FB.init({
  appId: '{socialApp}',
  version: 'v2.5' 
}); 
console.log(FB);    
});


$('#getInfo').click(function() {
FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
      console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
      FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
      });
    } else {
      console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
    }
    });
});
```

When FB.login() is called, I get the error saying:

```
FB.login() called before FB.init().
```

Why is this?. Also, when I console.log(FB) I do get the FB object back, but FB.init.appID and FB.init.version are not even set so I think FB.init is not initializing properly.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is copied from this [page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart/v2.5).

It seem like your function() in $.getScript did not work properly.

First, I think you should check your jquery plugins in your html page.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then, try to implement $(document).ready(); like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
  $.getScript('//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js', function(){
    FB.init({
      appId: '{socialApp}',
      version: 'v2.5'
    });     
    console.log(FB);  
  });
});
```

Hope this help!!!